# Should you use rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) or rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) for transparency in CSS?

Tags: css, colors

Should you use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` or `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` for transparency in CSS?

What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: one is white and one is black if you were to modify the opacity any. Otherwise it's still transparent. What is the scenario you have where this even came up as a question?

Comment: "@JackManey "Why would it matter?" I don't know. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The last parameter to the `rgba()` function is the "alpha" or "opacity" parameter. If you set it to `0` it will mean "completely transparent", and the first three parameters (the `red`, `green`, and `blue` channels) won't matter because you won't be able to see the color anyway.

With that in mind, I would choose `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` because:

1. it's less typing,
2. it keeps a few extra bytes out of your CSS file, and
3. you will see an obvious problem if the alpha value changes to something undesirable.

You *could* avoid the `rgba` model altogether and use the `transparent` keyword instead, which according to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent), is equivalent to "transparent black" and should compute to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`. For example:

```
h1 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This saves you yet another couple bytes while your intentions of using transparency are obvious (in case one is unfamiliar with RGBA).

As of CSS3, you can use the `transparent` keyword for any CSS property that accepts a color.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways of storing a color with alpha. The first is exactly as you see it, with each component as-is. The second is to use *pre-multiplied alpha*, where the color values are multiplied by the alpha after converting it to the range 0.0-1.0; this is done to make [compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) easier. Ordinarily you shouldn't notice or care which way is implemented by any particular engine, but there are corner cases where you might, for example if you tried to increase the opacity of the color. If you use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` you are less likely to to see a difference between the two approaches.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Specifically, the part that says "there are corner cases where you might, for example if you tried to increase the opacity of the color" is especially true when working with gradients, as the Image Values module [requires](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) that gradient colors are calculated in a pre-multiplied RGBA space. Note however that implementations still vary across browsers - in particular, some recent versions still violate that requirement in the spec (although to be fair, I believe it wasn't specified until a recent revision).

Answer (score 3):

There a small difference when u use rgba(255,255,255,**a**),background color becomes more and more lighter as the value of '**a**' increase from 0.0 to 1.0. Where as when use rgba(0,0,0,**a**), the background color becomes more and more darker as the value of '**a**' increases from 0.0 to 1.0.
Having said that, its clear that both (255,255,255,0) and (0,0,0,0) make background 
transparent.
(255,255,255,1) would make the background completely white where as  (0,0,0,1) would make background completely black.

Comment: This does not really answer the question and in any case does not contain information that is not already provided by at least one of the other answers to this question.

Comment: How can u say that it does not answer the question ! I tried to explain the concept behind rgba()  so that the pros and cons can be understood.

Comment: You explained what `rgba(...)` does, but that is not what the OP was asking. Just look at the other answers to this question, they are quite different from yours.

Comment: I actually found this helpful. I have a related question, though not exact;y the same, and would be inefficient to post a new question. I agree explanation of the concept is more important than a simple Pro/Con list with no understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `rgba(255,255,255,0)` because broken (newest) safari thinks that if you are using `transparent` or `rgba(0,0,0,0)` in linear-gradent you really mean `gray`, For more info please head to - [What happens in Safari with the transparent color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309641/what-happens-in-safari-with-the-transparent-color)