# WordPress transparent HTML widget background

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, transparent

Having a wordpress BoldGrid theme and setting the Custom JS & CSS like below.
I like to see a transparent background now but it´s not.

Custom JS & CSS:

```
.boldgrid-css{ background: white; } (This is not my code line)  
.opci{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
```

Then I use the CSS in a HTML widget like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body {
         text-align: left;
         color: green;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="opci">
         <h1>Work in progress...</h1>
         <p>Alpha released.</p>
         <p>april 4 2018.</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This does not make the background transparent, the background is white.

What am I missing?

It looks like the `.boldgrid-css` CSS (color white) is dominant somehow painting my Widget background white always

Here´s a screenshot of editor. The box saying "Work in progress..." I would like to have transparent background but it´s white

[image]

Comment: where is html tag with `boldgrid-css` class in the example you provided?

Comment: One can find them when sign into Wordpress BoldGrid

Comment: I see, but which tag contain that class? if you think, that the issue is with `.boldgrid-css` class, then wrote your own rules, like: `.boldgrid-css{ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }`, or `.boldgrid-css{ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important; }`

Comment: I only use the .opci class, the .boldgrid-css class is used by the theme. If I remove it I get an error. If I change it as you suggest then some other part of my site that uses the .boldgrid-css class, will change

Comment: sorry, but your update don't provide any more information, which may be helpfull. if you're far from html/css, then provide the url of the page. I can't suggest something other without looking at the full markup with all related css rules of that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions to get transparent background:

1. We are using `id` of your tag. `ID` must not be repeated at the page( sometimes that rule breakes because of bad coding ). Use this rule:

   ```
   #custom_html-3{
     background: transparent;
     border: none;
   }
   ```

   or if will not help, you can use `!important`, which will override all other rules, even if they are loaded later( exception may be other rules, which are using `!important`, too ):

   ```
   #custom_html-3{
     background: transparent !important;
     border: none !important;
   }
   ```
2. If `id` repeating on other pages, but you don't want to have transparent background on other pages, too, then we can be more specific, like:

   ```
   .page-id-12 #custom_html-3{
     background: transparent !important;
     border: none;
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   .page-id-12 #custom_html-3{
     background: transparent;
     border: none;
   }
   ```

Note: on other hand we can use `background: rgba(0,0,0,0);`. Difference good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32479188/8053001).

P.S. You can use this html markup:

```
  <style>
     body {
     text-align: left;
     color: green;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
  </style>
  <div class="opci">
     <h1>Work in progress...</h1>
     <p>Alpha released.</p>
     <p>april 4 2018.</p>
  </div>
```

You don't need to render full html inside of another one( `<doctype>,<html>,<head>,<body>` ). Also, your style rules you can add into **Customize -> Additional CSS**.

Answering to your question. Even without setting up to your `div.opci` `background` rules, it will be transparent, it's `inheritance`. More you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Comment: Thanks, I must read up on this dont understand much., when I add the nr:1 in the  Custom Theme CSS section where I already had the `.opci{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }` the "box" is transparent THANKS. I dont change the `<div class="opci">` in the HTML (picture in my Q) strange it´s working must learn more..

Comment: There´s stil a line box visible do you see? Is it possible to remove that? I know that´s a new Q

Comment: updated. you can use `#custom_html-3{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
} `

Comment: glad to be helpful